# C# , Visual Studio , Opening excel & then putting data into combo box

Tags: c#, excel

I have had an issue for the last few hours trying to pull the sheet names from an excel workbook and display for selection in a combobox. I managed to get it to work but i'm a little concerned its crude and not very efficient.

```
     private void btnChoose2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openfileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            openLabel.Text = openfileDialog1.SafeFileName;
            String filename = DialogResult.ToString();

            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = false;
            excelApp.Workbooks.Open(openfileDialog1.FileName);

            int rcountTag = excelApp.Sheets.Count - 1;

             for (int i = 1; i <= rcountTag + 1; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelApp.Worksheets;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

           excelSheets.get_Item(i);
                comboBoxMapping.Items.Insert(i - 1, worksheet.Name);

         }
        }
    }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a bit of work to do to make this code robust. You must call `excelApp.Quit()` before you finish with Excel. You also need to call `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance)` on **every COM instance** before they go out of scope. In your above code that would also include the `excelApp.Workbooks` reference in `excelApp.Workbooks.Open(...)` - you would need to get a reference to `excelApp.Workbooks` before calling open and then release the reference before finishing. You must be extremely careful with every single reference.

Comment: Thankyou Enigmativity , I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) if xlsx Excel format is to be dealt with.

Install epplus library from nuget package manager:
[image]

[image]

Then `using OfficeOpenXml;`

Get the list of sheet names:

```
ExcelPackage DocInv = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(ExcelDocument));
DocList = DocInv.Workbook.Worksheets.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Abbas , This is working perfect. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using a 3rd party library for this that will make your life much easier than messing with interop.

[Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/blob/develop/README.md)

This will let you get all the sheet names and read data into a DataTable which then you can access however you want to get whatever data you need out of it. The GitHub Read Me page has simple examples that should solve your issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitry , Greatly appreciated.